# In QGIS 3.x for Windows, is it possible to add more files to the Project > Open Recent menu?

Tags: qgis, qgis-3

Running QGIS 3.16 on Windows 10.

Right now, my "Project > Open Recent" menu shows a list of the last 19 .qgs/.qgz files I've opened.

I'd like to increment the number of recently opened files that are shown on that list.

Some time ago, I did something similar to the recent files list shown when right-clicking on the taskbar's QGIS pinned icon. After I tweaked it (I think there was some regediting involved, but can't really remember how off the top of my head, nevertheless) it's showing more recent files than it did by default.

I wonder if it's possible to increase the number of files shown inside the program's recent files menu?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, Settings -> Options -> Advanced -> App -> maxRecentProjects

Source : https://github.com/qgis/QGIS/issues/33720

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Nevertheless, since it's under the "Advanced" tab, and it explicitly warns about how changes there "are dangerous and can break your installation" (something I can't risk on production PCs), let me please ask you something. Have you tried this feature before? I know it sounds harmless and simple enough, and it's probably just an integer global variable, but globals do misbehave unpredictably kinda often so, do you have any experience using it? Or references from someone who does? Thanks again!